# Get the extension of a file contained in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ios5, nsstring

I have an NSMutable dictionary that contains file IDs and their filename+extension in the simple form of fileone.doc or filetwo.pdf. I need to determine what type of file it is to correctly display a related icon in my UITableView. Here is what I have done so far.

```
NSString *docInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]; //Determine what cell we are formatting
NSString *fileType = [contentFiles objectForKey:docInfo]; //Store the file name in a string
```

I wrote two regex to determine what type of file I'm looking at, but they never return a positive result. I haven't used regex in iOS programming before, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing it right, but I basically copied the code from the Class Description page.

```
    NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regexPDF = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/^.*\\.pdf$/" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSRegularExpression *regexDOC = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/^.*\\.(doc|docx)$/" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSUInteger numMatch = [regexPDF numberOfMatchesInString:fileType options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [fileType length])];
    NSLog(@"How many matches were found? %@", numMatch);
```

My questions would be, is there an easier way to do this? If not, are my regex incorrect? And finally if I have to use this, is it costly in run time? I don't know what the average amount of files a user will have will be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You're looking for `[fileType pathExtension]`

[NSString Documentation: pathExtension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension)

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that NSString have the `pathExtension` property

Comment: Objective-C just makes things so easy; I need to not think of such hard solutions! Thank you David.

Comment: Im glad I didnt try and make this function myself

Answer (score 7):

```
//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: fileType];
NSLog(@"extension: %@", [fileType pathExtension]);
```

*Edit* you can use pathExtension on NSString

Thanks to David Barry

Comment: You can call pathExtension directly on the String, no need to create an NSURL first.

Comment: Why have you just ripped the answer above and then credited him?

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
NSString *fileName = @"resume.doc";  
NSString *ext = [fileName pathExtension];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me.

```
NSString *fileName = @"yourFileName.pdf";
NSString *ext = [fileName pathExtension];
```

Documentation here for [NSString pathExtension](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [fileType pathExtension] to get the extension of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 you could use an extension:

```
extension String {

public func getExtension() -> String? {

        let ext = (self as NSString).pathExtension

        if ext.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }

        return ext
    }
}
```