# How to check the data exists in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I click the button and check if the (.png) or another data is exists in NSDocumentDirectory.  if exists push the view controller or not.

I tried this,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"u0-1b.png"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SavedViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
else
    NSLog(@"file doesnt exist");
```

Here I given the full image name (u1-1b.png) it's woking but I want to check the data or extension (.png, or ).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245123/get-the-extension-of-a-file-contained-in-an-nsstring

Comment: it is not a duplicate.  you given the link is different question

Comment: Then what you mean `check the data or extension(.png,..)`?

Comment: You are asking if you can search a path for .png files ?

Comment: it is possible to check in that folder using extension instead of given full name (filename.png)

Comment: You mean u need to search if a ".png" file is present or not ? If YES Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob

Comment: just i want to know png file exists push view controller or not…. See my above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage it by using following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);

if(filePathsArray.count > 0)
{
     // data is exist;
}
else
{
  // data does not exist;
}
```

You can get the path for each object in filePathsArray by using the below code

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < filePathsArray.count; i++)
{
   NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

If you want to get extension of any file then **@Basheer_CAD's** Like is helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

This method return to you all the files paths and extensions in NSDictionary in your document dir, make use of it. The `directory` parameter, is used if you want to search for subfolders, example: if you have files in folder `mmm` pass `@"/mmm"`, otherwise pass `nil`

```
 - (NSDictionary*)listOfFilesAtDirectory:(NSString*)directory
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *filesAtDirectory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSString *documentsDir = [self documentsDirectory];
        NSString *givenDirectory = [documentsDir stringByAppendingString:directory];
        NSError *searchErr = nil;

        NSArray *arrFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:givenDirectory
                                                                                error:&searchErr];
        if(!searchErr)
        {
            for(NSString *strFileNameAndExtension in arrFiles)
            {
                NSString *strFilePath = [givenDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileNameAndExtension];
                [filesAtDirectory setObject:strFileNameAndExtension forKey:strFilePath];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading files in this directory: %@, \n Error description:%@", directory, searchErr.description);
        }

        return filesAtDirectory;
    }
```

**Just in case this is documentsDirectory method**

```
- (NSString*)documentsDirectory
{
    NSString *strRootPath  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return strRootPath;
}
```